# Printing integer variable and string on same line in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok so I have searched for an answer to this on Technet, to no avail.

I just want to print an integer variable concatenated with two String variables.

This is my code, that doesn't run:

```
print 'There are ' + @Number + ' alias combinations did not match a record'
```

It seems like such a basic feature, I couldn't imagine that it is not possible in T-SQL. But if it isn't possible, please just say so. I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Comment: `print 'There are ' + CAST(@Number AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' alias combinations did not match a record'`

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```sql
declare @x INT = 1 /* Declares an integer variable named "x" with the value of 1 */
    
PRINT 'There are ' + CAST(@x AS VARCHAR) + ' alias combinations did not match a record' /* Prints a string concatenated with x casted as a varchar */
```

Comment: I like the Cast Method. Short and sweet, and keeps the original variable as an int, which I need.

Comment: Ha, I would have accepted it immediately but it wouldn't let me for another 6 minutes.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to manually cast types, you can use the [`CONCAT`-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) for this.

```sql
PRINT CONCAT('There are ', @Number, ' alias combinations did not match a record')
```

Answer (score 12):

Numbers have [higher precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than strings so of course the `+` operators want to convert your strings into numbers before adding.

You could do:

```
print 'There are ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@Number) +
      ' alias combinations did not match a record'
```

or use the (rather limited) formatting facilities of [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

```
RAISERROR('There are %i alias combinations did not match a record',10,1,@Number)
WITH NOWAIT
```

Comment: Thank you for the background info. I didn't realize that T-SQL have so much thought to precedence when doing simple print statements.

Comment: @AdamJ -it's nothing to do with `print` statements, per-se. T-SQL is a very simple, quite old-fashioned language. In T-SQL, all inputs to an operator must be of the same type.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I forget sometimes that SQL was created in the 70's. SQL Server has a fairly sleek look to it (in my opinion) which I think makes it seem more modern than it truly is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't combine a character string and numeric string.  You need to convert the number to a string using either CONVERT or CAST.

For example:

```
print 'There are ' + cast(@Number as varchar) + ' alias combinations did not match a record'
```

or

```
print 'There are ' + convert(varchar,@Number) + ' alias combinations did not match a record'
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check if you have set and **initial value** for int and decimal values to be printed.

This sample is printing an empty line

```
declare @Number INT
print 'The number is : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number)
```

And this sample is printing -> The number is : 1

```
declare @Number INT = 1
print 'The number is : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one,

```
declare @Number INT = 5                            
print 'There are ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number) + ' alias combinations did not match a record'
```